# Confused with failed Audit in Late Answers

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed the following audit in the Late Answers review queue when I selected 'No Action Needed':
https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/13939178

Supposedly the answer did not answer the question. I however disagree with that statement.

The question asks why fonts appear differently in different browsers:
[Differences in font size across safari and chrome with no css involved. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986397/differences-in-font-size-across-safari-and-chrome-with-no-css-involved-why)

I won't argue that the late answer does not have the best grammar and doesn't straight out explain why the fonts are different. However, the answer does give ideas that would help solve the OP's problem of different font sizes. I feel that it is useful and would be useful to future readers with similar problems.

> To prevent such issues add reset.css. further if u have used custom webfonts try to add other fallback fonts as well. It may also help you.

If you look at the accepted answer, it really doesn't differ much from the failed audit answer. The accepted answer adds an explanation to the problem which is great, yet both answers suggest the same actual solution to the problem, which is the part of the answer most askers really care about.

> Because all browsers render font and elements differently. This is why you need to create a reset.css file in order to get all browsers to a baseline and acting in the same way towards your font, ul, li etc etc.

If anything, the second answer just adds an additional solution idea not mentioned in the accepted answer.

The answer might not be the best answer and may improve with editing, yet should I have really flagged this as a bad answer?

Comment: You found yet another case of the Low Quality Posts queue [doing it wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)...

Comment: At least you could have edited it.  There were a couple of typos and if I can spot them anyone should be able to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The answer might not be the best answer and may improve with editing,

But you specifically said that *there was nothing at all that you could do* to improve this answer with your review.  If you felt the answer needed editing, you should have edited it to improve it.  If you felt that the answer wasn't well explained, you should have commented to that effect.  Given that you felt it was not a good answer, you should have *voted* to that effect.

In this meta question alone you've listed off *several* actions that you feel were merited for this answer, so failing you for indicating that *there isn't any possible action that you could have taken* is clearly correct.  You knew better yourself, and simply choose not to act anyway.

Comment: I always forget all those rules... wouldn't clicking edit fail the review audit as well?

Comment: @Tunaki No.  The post was problematic, edit it to (try to) fix those problems would pass the audit.

Comment: @Servy I agree that I should have edited it, yet it seems like this answer was put as an audit because it was deemed as "not an answer". That part is what I don't agree with.

Comment: @TotZam Then feel free to ask a meta question to discuss whether or not that answer is or is not an answer, and whether or not it merits deletion as a result (entirely independently of your audit).  Since you merely asked about the appropriateness of you failing your audit, that's what you've gotten an answer for.

Answer (score 2):

The first post and late answer queues are review queues designed to make sure that new users get immediate feedback on their answers.  This means that it is important to leave comments, make edits, and vote on their posts.

While this answer is not delete-worthy, it needs some serious work.  The answer is unclear and does not provide any explanation for why it works.  Additionally, it is poorly formatted and has terrible grammar.  These aspects definitely require your intervention as a reviewer.  Ideally that's an edit, but it could also be a comment or a downvote.  Choosing "No action needed" is definitely wrong, and that's why you failed the audit.